# Duplicate Elements in HashSet Java

Tags: java, hashset, duplicates

I am creating a web crawler that crawls through .edu domains. I am using jsoup to parse my html files for anchor links. Then I add the links to a HashSet because I don't want to have duplicate urls. However, when I print out my HashSet, I have duplicates of several urls.

I declared my set as a member function

```
private Set <String> url = new HashSet<String>();

public void jsoupParse(String htmlFile, String baseUrl){
    try{
        File input = new File(htmlFile);
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", baseUrl);
        Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
        for (Element link : links) {
            String linkHref = link.attr("abs:href");
            linkHref.trim();
            url.add(linkHref);
        }
        printCollection();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In my seed file, I have 4 urls, so I have 4 htmlFiles. When I print out I get 659 entries. Down below is a sample of my output. For example, this particular url gets printed out four times. http://diversity.mit.edu/diversity-summit-2015/

My Output:

```
http://web.mit.edu/admissions/
http://diversity.mit.edu/
http://newsoffice.mit.edu
http://whereis.mit.edu
http://diversity.mit.edu/diversity-summit-2015/
http://diversity.mit.edu/event/mlk-celebration-2015/
http://mit.edu/site/?ref=mithomepage
http://ki.mit.edu
http://web.mit.edu/athletics/www/
http://twitter.com/mit
http://libraries.mit.edu/
http://web.mit.edu/faculty/
....
http://newsoffice.mit.edu
http://strategiccommunications.ucr.edu/
http://hvrd.me/GmV2x
http://diversity.mit.edu/diversity-summit-2015/
http://ucr.edu/
http://hvrd.me/IaiDY
http://ki.mit.edu
http://stanford.edu/academics/programs
http://news.stanford.edu/news/2015/january/jones-students-econversation-012815.html
http://harvard.edu/#skip
http://campusmap.ucr.edu/?loc=HINHL
```

Comment: Can you show your output containing duplicates?

Answer (score 3):

For a widely used well established language like Java, better suspect your program problem.

You can resolve this by print out the `hashCode()` and the `toByteArray()` of your URL string and this could give you the reason why it's different.

My guess are either

1. You misread the difference
2. Your string contains leading and/or trailing space (use `trim()` to remove)
3. Your string has UTF-8 chars which looks the same but are different.

Comment: Could you please explain what you meant by the first guess? I added trim to my string, but I still get the same result.  Also, by your third guess, do you mean to use charset UTF-16?

Comment: I find it interesting that since I have 4 url seeds. I repeat my url four times.

Comment: 1. Just means if you misread it by eyeball... If you cannot resolve it by 2. it probably means you have 2 different chars looking the same but with different code. Try to print toByteArray() then you can see the raw byte array to determine how it's different.